# How to save Excel workbook into a general path using VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, save

I want to know how to save an Excel workbook into a general path. I want to use my program on various computers, and I don't want to change the path location in my program every time I use my program on a new computer.

Comment: Please look at [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.StartupPath` like this:

```
Dim myPath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\myexcel.xlsx"
```

This will save your file into the program's folder.